# How can i resolve this Remix compilation errors "TypeError: Invalid array length, expected integer literal or constant expression & Data location "

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20

Here are the errors i'm getting with the code all coming from balanceOf function:

Errors:

```
TypeError: Data location must be "memory" or "calldata" for parameter in function, but none was given.
--> contracts/Htoken.sol:39:24:
|
39 | function balanceOf(address [msg.sender]) public override view returns (uint256) {
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

TypeError: Invalid array length, expected integer literal or constant expression.
--> contracts/Htoken.sol:39:33:
|
39 | function balanceOf(address [msg.sender]) public override view returns (uint256) {
| ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Smart Contract Code:

```
constructor() {
    balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply_;
}

function totalSupply() public override view returns (uint256) {
    return totalSupply_;
}

function balanceOf(address [msg.sender]) public override view returns (uint256) {
    return balances[msg.sender];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `balanceOf()` function signature. In details, you cannot use `msg.sender` global keyword as parameter. To solve this problem you can try this:

```
function balanceOf(address _address) public override view returns (uint256) {
    return balances[_address];
}
```

I changed input parameter with an input data that when you'll call this function you will have to pass it.
Another option is: don't have input parameter and use msg.sender directly into balances mapping in this way:

```
function balanceOf() public override view returns (uint256) {
    return balances[msg.sender];
}
```

Comment: Hello @Kerry99,
that didn't solve the problem

Comment: Can you include all your smart contract code?